# Converting NodeList to String in Java

Tags: java, xpath, tostring, nodelist

I'm trying to convert NodeList to String so I can manipulate it in whichever way I want, but I can't seem to find an answer online.

I've tried storing the NodeList in a Node array, but all the data printed out would be null.

**TextingXPath.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestingXPath {


static Node[] copy;
static int length;

public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException {

    URL obj = new URL("http://jbossews-ashton.rhcloud.com/testXML.jsp");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == 200) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                .newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dDoc = builder.parse(con.getInputStream());

            XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            Node node = (Node) xPath.evaluate(
                    "/HDB/Resident[@Name='Batman ']/Preference", dDoc,
                    XPathConstants.NODE);
            if (null != node) {
                NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();
                for (int i = 0; null != nodeList
                        && i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node nod = nodeList.item(i);
                    if (nod.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                        {

                        ...

                        }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: try System.out.println(nod.getTextContent());

Comment: Your code doesn't show any actual attempt to convert to string. What do you want to convert exactly? What's in those "..."? And why do you think that String will allow you better manipulation than DOM does?

Comment: @RealSkeptic The "..." was where I attempted to solve the problem on my own, but since it didn't work, I removed the entire chunk of code. I wish to use the stored values of NodeList in another class

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This Convert Node to String it gets the node as XML as is, if you need only the content with no XML use `getTextContent`

```
Node elem = nodeList.item(i);//Your Node
StringWriter buf = new StringWriter();
Transformer xform = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes"); // optional
xform.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes"); // optional
xform.transform(new DOMSource(elem), new StreamResult(buf));
System.out.println(buf.toString()); // your string
```

Answer (score 0):

For printing `Preference1` elements

use `System.out.println(nod.getTextContent());`

Comment: This only prints "actual text content" i.e. "c" of `<b>c</b>` but not any internal nodes, sadly...

Answer (score -1):

you can print the node names as follows

```
System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
```