# XML Parse with Xpath in Java to get all elements with values matches

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I have a dynamic xml file that has not specific structure. For example;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:yin:1" name="ui-leaf-type-second">
    <yang-version value="1.1"/>
    <namespace uri="ui-leaf-type-second"/>
    <prefix value="uil-type-second"/>
    <description>
        <text>This is basic yang types example</text>
    </description>
    <revision date="2022-02-02">
        <description>
            <text>initial revision</text>
        </description>
    </revision>
    <typedef name="laser-range">
        <type name="uint8">
            <range value="0 .. 100"/>
        </type>
        <description>
            <text>Percentage</text>
        </description>
        
    </typedef>
    <grouping name="grp-range">
        <leaf name="name-of-range">
            <type name="boolean"/>
        </leaf>
    </grouping>
    <container name="cnt-range">
        <uses name="grp-range"/>
    </container>
</module>
```

I want to get full element which has value that I searching for.
For example, I want to get an element that have **@name = "laser-range"**

It should return whole element:

```
<typedef name="laser-range">
        <type name="uint8">
            <range value="0 .. 100"/>
        </type>
        <description>
            <text>Percentage</text>
        </description>

</typedef>
```

If I search for **@name='name-of-range'**, it should return

```
<leaf name="name-of-range">
    <type name="boolean"/>
</leaf>
```

I tried to get those with xpath but it is returning only values in the tag.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(tmpFile.toFile());

            XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
            // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//*[@name='laser-range']");

            Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            //result includes only "Percentage"
}
```

I also tried to use @* notation of xpath but it could not give me a solution too.

So, how can I make it? Can someone to show me a way?

Comment: If I run that code, `nodes.item(0).getLocalName()` is `typedef`; if I stringify it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31399798/converting-nodelist-to-string-in-java), I get the whole element.

Comment: Your XPath is ok

Comment: @Joe thank you for answer. It solved my problem. By the way, there could be more than one typedef element in xml. So, I can find the right one after visiting all nodes and check if(buf.toString().contains("laser-range")) if I am searching for "laser-range". Is there different way to get right typdef element without traverse?

Comment: @Oguz I'm not sure I understand that requirement; the XPath has already selected only the elements with a `name` of `laser-range`.

Comment: @Joe I see now. I though all typedef tags come from xml. It was my mistake. Thank you again.